# AJAX post request does not find Spring MVC controller, returns 404

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I am very new to the Spring MVC framework, and am trying getting my hands dirty. Here is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax("/spn/list/next"...
```

Here is my controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class ListNexPageController {
private static final String NEXT_PAGE_LEADS_URl="/list/next";

@RequestMapping(value=NEXT_PAGE_LEADS_URl,method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void getNextPage(@RequestParam(value="pageKey",required=false)String pageKeyString,@RequestParam(value="category",required=false)String category){
    Log.info("URL hit, yay!");
}
```

}

The POST call returns a 404 error, implying that it can't find the controller. Can someone please hint at what I might be doing wrong?
Note that I am sending an array of objects as parameter in the POST call.

Here is the complete AJAX call:

```
$.ajax("/spn/list/next", {
          method: 'post',
          params: AJAX_DATA
});
```

Comment: Show how do you actually call the controller

Comment: I have added the complete AJAX call in the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is mapped to "/list/next" but your AJAX method calls "/spn/list/next".
You can try to add the context path it will be (if it's JSP):

```
$.ajax("${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/list/next", {
      method: 'post',
      params: AJAX_DATA
});
```

Comment: Let me try that. Btw when I removed the spn part from the AJAX url, it returns an unauthorized 401 error. So, I guess I messed-up with the url.

Comment: @PrashantPandey Do you have Spring Security configuration?

Comment: Added that now, it now gives a 500 error. I guess my problem is solved, then. Thanks for your time.